# Как определить, работает ли программа из-под Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Как работающая Java-программа может определить, запущена ли она из-под Eclipse по команде Run (Ctrl+F11), или работает под JVM, запущенной из командной строки отдельно от eclipse, типа `>java -cp myPath MyMainClass'?

Comment: А разьве эклипс не запускает программу из командной строки встроенными стредствами?

Comment: Переменную среды можно установить в Eclipse для запуска. А в приложении проверять её в `System.getenv`.

Comment: @Suvitruf да, но хотелось бы найти более простой способ, не требующий специальных телодвижений от пользователя Eclipse. Я передаю заказчику проект в виде (JAR + набор откомпилированных классов + Eclipse project), Будущие пользователи - не эксперты по eclipse, и не хочется создавать им лишних заморочек. Должны быть очень простые процедуры, описанные в короткой инструкции для пользователя. В коде можно изгаляться как угодно, ограничений нет.

Answer (score 0):

В Intelij Idea в System.getProperties() добавляется:

"idea.launcher.bin.path" со значением 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA xxx\bin"

Тестировалось на Idea 2016.3 под JDK 1.8.0_102

Если Вам не принципиально, можете попробовать бесплатную Community Edition.

В Eclipse, к сожалению, такого не нашёл.

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно именно eclipse. Idea не годится.